# commit transaction ONLY when ALL queries succeed

Tags: sql, transactions, mariadb

I have a simple query

```
START TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES(5); 

ROLLBACK;
```

Basically, its 2 parts: 1st creates a table. 2nd inserts into table `Table_2`.

`Table_2` does not exist hence causing an issue. BUT it still creates the table `Persons` and does NOT rollback.

The same can be done with simply 2 insert queries (1st the correct one and the 2nd a falsy one).

How do I properly create a transaction that will rollback everything if even 1 query fails?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-statements-that-cause-an-implicit-commit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct but it fails because MariaDB does not support transactional DDL statements. If your transaction would've consistent only of DML statements (`INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT` etc.) it would've behaved as you expected.

[This list](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-statements-that-cause-an-implicit-commit/) contains all the statements that behave as if you did a `COMMIT` right before them (i.e. they perform an implicit commit). The most notable of these are:

- `CREATE TABLE`
- `ALTER TABLE`
- `DROP TABLE`
- `RENAME TABLE`
- `TRUNCATE TABLE`
- `CREATE INDEX`
- `DROP INDEX`

A recent improvement in MariaDB 10.6 is [the atomic DDL support](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/atomic-ddl/). This means that even if these statements are not transactional (you can't roll them back) they are atomic: if you start a DDL statement and the server suddenly stops (e.g. due to a power outage), you'll be guaranteed to not corrupt your databse.